# Wordpress load sidebar.php with Ajax - loads wrong content (index.php instead)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have almost got to load the sidebar in wordpress with Ajax, using this example (**https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61830/use-ajax-request-to-load-sidebar**)

**but instead of loading my new sidebar-ajax.php, it always loads the index.php instead in the div called "sidebar".**
I have the Feeling, that my function (get_template_part('sidebar-ajax');
) is not executed properly, but cannot find the error

in my functions.php i have inserted:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
/* load your js file in footer */
wp_enqueue_script('theme-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your-js-file.js',   
false, false, true);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_sidebar', 'check_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_sidebar', 'check_ajax');
function check_ajax() {
?>
get_template_part('sidebar-ajax');
<?php
} ?>
```

my js. file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: location.href,
data: { get_ajax_sidebar: 1 },
success: function(data){
    jQuery('#sidebar').html(data);
}
});
```

and in my index.php i have added:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

any help is really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: whats inside the "location.href" when the page is loaded/ the function is triggered ?

Comment: i dont quite understand the question - sorry, i am a beginner with JavaScript - i guess it is the index.php ?

Comment: try a console.log(location.href) before your ajax-call. You can see the output in the console of e.g. Firebug. Now you can check if it's the url that should be called

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_part()` is outside of php tags... why? I like to use [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar). Try this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_ajax_sidebar', 'check_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_sidebar', 'check_ajax' );
function check_ajax() {
    get_sidebar( 'ajax' );
}
```

Comment: that is true, but it is the same in the original code - demo (see link), and on the other thread it says that it is working.... so i assumed i copy/paste the same code for my site

Comment: If you are not actually calling the function in php you won't be able to use it. You HAVE to get rid of the php tags around 
`get_template_part('sidebar-ajax');`

Comment: ok, i did that. still not working. you can check at www.shopmajorbrands.com/ajax/

Comment: I think you have more errors in your page for example a 404 on `your-jsc-file.js` if that is the file holding your jquery than it won't work.

Comment: So in the end this was correct, since you needed to remove the php tags and fix the enqueueing of the scripts... if so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but, the reason this isn't working is because you need the correct url to call the ajax function. On the back end of wordpress this is done automatically and defined in a javascript variable called ajaxurl. On the front end you have to define this yourself, it's quite straight-forward. In your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_head','yourfunctionname_ajaxurl');
function yourfunctionname_ajaxurl() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Now you can change the javascript code to:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: { action:'get_ajax_sidebar' },
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#sidebar').html(data);
    }
});
```

More information can be found on the codex here: [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)